# Can I recover the ether sent to the scam address?

Tags: dapps

I have remitted Ethereum to the Ico token scam address. Can I get a refund? please help
anyone can i help?
my ethwallet 0x8803C24905E9E0Ff4bd0b1Bae444ad4C93E793E9 and 0xe279409D91ddD379B36Ab8Ab84DCF819C77A8893
scammer wallet 0xd7BffEf9ab71e18F2Baf7e3807ed32da5bb7A447

I sent total 21 ETH to scam address.

Comment: [I added a generic question and answer: I got scammed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-on-ethereum-what-to-do/152374#152374).